# How to set Optional<Long> data type variable value in a Long data type variable?

Tags: java, spring-boot, java-8

I have variable which is of type Long. I am getting a Optional value from a request. How to set Optional value in a Long variable.

Comment: Before asking here, you should **read the documentation**, i.e. the javadoc of [`Optional`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Optional.html). Look through the [list of methods](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Optional.html#method.summary) and iff any of them return the value, i.e. the return type is `T`. --- Question down-voted because it "does not show any research effort" *(quoting tooltip of down-vote button)*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the `get()` method to get the long value from the optional. Also you can also use `orElse` or `orElseGet` or `orElseThrow` to return default value, another long value from differnet invocation or throw an exception.

```
if(res.isPresent()){
    Long value = res.get();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can initialize the Long with Optional#get, Optional#orElseGet, or Optional#orElseThrow. If you use Optional#get and no value is present, a `NoSuchElementException` is thrown so use Optional#isPresent to ensure the Optional isn't empty.

```java
long value = optionalReference.orElseThrow(IllegalStateException::new);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use one of those three see difference here : [Optional documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Optional.html)

1. get();
2. orElseThrow(Supplier<? extends X> exceptionSupplier);
3. orElse(T other);